# unable to connect cf ic login

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I am trying to have a container running in `Bluemix`. I have cf version 6.15, and I want to deploy a docker file I have a connection failed. Any experience around to help me with this? I appreciate in advance.

The commands I am running from windows are the following:

`c:\build>cf login -u myusername -o myusername -s myspace`

All authentication at this point is ok.

`c:\build>cf ic login`

And I have this error:

```
Client certificates are being retrieved from IBM Containers...
FAILED
Put https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443/v3/tlskey/refresh: dial tcp 
198.23.117.148:8443: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

In particular, I am trying to do the following coding which I followed step by [step](https://developer.ibm.com/integration/docs/ibm-integration-bus/using-the-containers-service-to-run-ibm-integration-bus-in-bluemix-in-10-easy-steps/).

Also, this is a `Windows 7` and I have no docker for windows installed (not sure it is needed). Many thanks!

Comment: A Docker environment is needed for the tutorial, see the upper third of the tutorial on how to set it up.

Comment: @data_henrik thanks for your reply. Do you mean the lack of Docker in my windows is the reason "cf ic login" fails? Thank you.

Comment: You need Docker for the tutorial anyway. Why not try it out...? :) The error looks more like a connectivity issue, but the Bluemix status indicates everything ok. https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

Comment: @data_henrik thanks for your suggestion and for the service status link. Just noticed there is a unresolved issue since 11 Feb 2016 "Issues with logging and monitoring of Containers and VMs in US South". I am not an expert but that could be related to the "cf ic login" error. I could install Docker, but want to make sure this error is not my side. Cheers!

Comment: This has now been resolved. It was a proxy/port setting at network level. Basically the place I work had to open the connection for my computer and now all works well. As I suspected, there was no need to install docker in my windows.